# GPU Proof-of-work

Tags: attach-to-tangle, consensus, proof-of-work

Is Iota proof of work being done only on CPUs right now, or also GPUs?

I see people mentioning their GPU when posting about how long it takes their full node to do PoW, but I thought that required CUDA programming (for Nvidia) or OpenCL? (for AMD). I know the ternary JINN processor is supposed to be more efficient for PoW, but who knows when that is coming.

Comment: You can choose a WebGl implementation, which runs on the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

IOTA has some OpenCL context Library: https://github.com/iotaledger/clcontext

But I don't know what you can do with it. Maybe this is what people ware referring to.

Answer (score 1):

A team working on a spamming tool tried to implement GPU transaction spammer but they ran into big issues with OpenCL as of 20/2/2018. The library is not ready as it always crashes, so it's whether to dig into the OpenCL or wait.